# Git still ignores case change and refuses to rename directory after updating `core.ignorecase`

Tags: git

I need to change the name of a directory from `buttons` to `Buttons`.

Before doing this I checked if Git was ignoring case changes. I ran:

`git config --global --get core.ignorecase`

which returned `true`.

I then changed the directory name in the IDE, but git didn't recognise the changes.

I then tried:

`git mv /buttons/ /Buttons/`

but got the response:

```
fatal: renaming '/Buttons/' failed: Invalid argument
```

I tried `git mv -f /buttons/ /Buttons/` too, with the same results.

Anyone know what I can do to update the directory?

Comment: Are you on Windows? Have you tried using a temporary directory name? `buttons/ -> buttons1/`, `buttons1/ -> Buttons/` (note the absence of a prefix slash, because that'd reference your drive root).

Comment: `core.ignorecase` is a statement about the file system the repository is on, not a flag you can toggle.  What operating system and file system are you using?

Comment: This is in MacOS. Don't know the file system.